# segmentation fault with single integer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, int

So I'm making a `class` which is just an easy way to manipulate an `array` of a different `class` and perform a few operations on it (fractions if you wanted to know)

NOTE: this is my homework but I don't think this violates any kind of rule because I'm not asking how to do it, but what the issue is. However, if you would have any sort of moral dilemma with this, I'm just letting you know now.

The function uses a for loop to go through an array - but not out of array bounds, because I changed the code to not even use the array

```
for (int i = first - 1; i < last - 1; i++) cout << i;
```

and I still get a seg fault when `i` is 4.
In the scope of the function call, `i` is not a variable.

The line of output from this call is

```
0123
Segmentation fault
```

so for all I know, changing `i` to 4 causes the error.

Member data in the class is

```
private:
    int size;
    Fraction arr[20];
```

the function in the header is

```
Fraction Product(int first, int last) const;
```

and the code that uses it preceding the error is this (from Bob Myers FSU CS Dept)
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/hw/hw4files/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "flist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int start;
   Fraction entry;
   FList a;
   cout << "Welcome!\n";
   cout << a;
   cout << "How many numbers to start with (1 - 20)? ";
   cin >> start;
   cout << "Please input the " << start << " starting fractions\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
   {
        cout << "Fraction #" << (i+1) << ":  ";
    entry.Input();
    a.Insert(entry);
   }
   cout << "\nHere's the list:\n" << a;

   cout << "Size of list = " << a.Size() << '\n';
   cout << "Sum of items in list = " << a.Sum();
   cout << "\nProduct of first 5 fractions in list = " << a.Product(1,5);
```

I don't know much about computer organization and what's really going on behind memory allocation but I don't see how an integer can change value without changing the amount of bytes used and then become invalid memory, so I would really appreciate someone who can say I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: Use `std::endl` or `std::flush` so that your program outputs everything before crashing. The output `0123` doesn't tell you where it crashes if you don't flush the output after every print statement.

Comment: Use a debugger to tell us where the fault occurs

Comment: Your code sample does not seem to include the line that you mention at the start of the question. Please post a [complete program showing the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seeing what `i` is being used for would help quite a bit.  I assume it's an array index and that you're accessing the array out of bounds.  The `-1` is a red flag.

Comment: Forgot to flush, thanks @zenith 
The error was a few lines later, the whole thing ran.